# Passar query nativa por parâmetro para Interface JpaRepository

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-jpa

Preciso criar uma interface que extende o JpaRepository onde eu quero passar uma query(select) nativa por parâmetro ao invés de deixar estático dentro da anotação `@Query`.
Ao invés de usar `@Query(value = "select * from a where a = :a", nativeQuery = true)` eu quero usar o código exemplificado abaixo.

```java
 public interface MeuRepository extends JpaRepository<MeuEntity, Integer>{

     @Query(value = query, nativeQuery = true)
     List<MeuEntity> findCustomNativeQuery(String query);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso não tem como, você tem que usar o `EntityManager`, segue um exemplo:

```
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager manager;

public List<MeuEntity> findCustomNativeQuery(String query) {
    return manager.createNativeQuery(query, MeuEntity.class).getResultList();
}
```